# ionic2 push notification error : device has not fired after 5 seconds

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, push-notification, ionic2, push

Im trying to implement push notification in latest ionic2 release and this is my code following this doc : https://medium.com/@ankushaggarwal/push-notifications-in-ionic-2-658461108c59#.2oe9zk3z5

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform, Nav, AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar, Splashscreen, AdMob, Push } from 'ionic-native';

import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { Config } from '../providers/config';

import { DownloadPage } from '../pages/download/download'

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {    
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;
  rootPage = HomePage;

  constructor(public platform: Platform, public conf: Config, public alertCtrl: AlertController) {

    platform.ready().then(() => {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
      Splashscreen.hide();

        AdMob.createBanner({adId : this.conf.admobBanner, isTesting:true}).then(() =>   { AdMob.showBanner(8); });

      this.initPushNotification();


    });

  }

    initPushNotification(){
    if (!this.platform.is('cordova')) {
      console.warn("Push notifications not initialized. Cordova is not available - Run in physical device");
      return;
    }
    let push = Push.init({
      android: {
        senderID: "xxxxxx" // I have senderID
      },
      ios: {
        alert: "true",
        badge: false,
        sound: "true"
      },
      windows: {}
    });

    push.on('registration', (data) => {
      console.log("device token ->", data.registrationId);
      //TODO - send device token to server
    });
    push.on('notification', (data) => {
      console.log('message', data.message);
      let self = this;
      //if user using app and push notification comes
      if (data.additionalData.foreground) {
        // if application open, show popup
        let confirmAlert = this.alertCtrl.create({
          title: 'New Notification',
          message: data.message,
          buttons: [{
            text: 'Ignore',
            role: 'cancel'
          }, {
            text: 'View',
            handler: () => {
              //TODO: Your logic here
              self.nav.push(DownloadPage);
            }
          }]
        });
        confirmAlert.present();
      } else {
        //if user NOT using app and push notification comes
        //TODO: Your logic on click of push notification directly
        self.nav.push(DownloadPage);
        console.log("Push notification clicked");
      }
    });
    push.on('error', (e) => {
      console.log(e.message);
    });
  }
}
```

and I already got the FCM server key and senderID and setup the ionic Icloud

so when I run it on my android device it says gives this errors in the console :

```
[14:41:35]  console.log: deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds. 
[14:41:35]  console.log: Channel not fired: onPluginsReady 
[14:41:35]  console.log: Channel not fired: onCordovaReady 
[14:41:36]  error opening ws message: {"category":"console","type":"log","data":["DEVICE READY FIRED AFTER",4182,"ms"]} 
[14:41:47]  error opening ws message: {"category":"console","type":"log","data":["device token 
            ->","cJ5Iw6b9OpW:APA91bHmplWN80qKFld0wtcfnFCmO5kjFHj1tuCwMkCOMKYcZ-HbMC4i7Vg1hIbdL9d0eDdl2c7MWsJ79XrLQ3m4cnEwj6I7E3s2eDO58yrqg9C_xGsLkLWYWQ"]}
```

Comment: I already did push notification using OneSignal API, Push notification of ionic cloud had have a lot of problems then which I think is fixed by now.

Answer (score 0):

you can change from :

```
console.log("device token ->", data.registrationId);
```

to:

```
console.log("device token:");
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Hope this helps